# Calculating Maximum Consecutive Drought Events

Tags: r

I am working on a project in R where I am calculating drought events based on the Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) using the SPEI package. I have successfully calculated drought events for each month using the overlay function and then proceeded to calculate the maximum consecutive drought events for each year using stackApply.

```
# Create a function for drought event calculation
calculateDroughtEvent <- function(spi_value) {
  ifelse(spi_value < -1.0, 1, 0)
}

# Apply the function to each layer of the SPI raster brick using overlay
drought_events <- overlay(rstSPEI3, fun = calculateDroughtEvent)

# Function to calculate maximum consecutive events
calculateMaxConsecutive <- function(x) {
  runs <- rle(x)
  if (any(runs$values == 1)) {
    max_consecutive <- max(runs$lengths[runs$values == 1], na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    max_consecutive <- 0
  }
  return(max_consecutive)
}

# Apply the function to calculate maximum consecutive drought events for each year
annual_drought_events <- stackApply(drought_events, rep(seq(1, nlayers(drought_events)/12),
                                                        each = 12), fun = calculateMaxConsecutive)
```

However, I encountered an issue with the stackApply function that resulted in an error related to the na.rm argument. I tried several modifications, but the problem persists.

How to correctly calculate the maximum consecutive drought events each year?